# Show API results in div with vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Trying to set up dynamic buttons to retrieve some data from an API call. But I can't seem to push the data array to the template and the div.

My VueJS look like this:

```
var example = new Vue({
  el: '#example',
    data: function () {
        return {
            list: []
        }
    },

  methods: {
    fetchMovies: function (city) {
        $.getJSON('api/city?city=' + city, function(tasks) {
            console.log(tasks); // What i receive from API
            console.log(city); // What is being sent from button
            this.list = tasks; // API results in to list array
            this.todos.push(this.newTodoText); // Push results to div
        }.bind(this))
    }
  }
});
```

And the button, and template looks like this:

```
<div id="example">
  <button v-on:click="fetchMovies('stockholm')">Greet</button>
</div>

<div id="exampleList">
    <tasks></tasks>
</div>

<template id="tasks-template">
    <div>
        <h1>vue grjer!</h1>
        <ul class="list-group">
            @{{ list.name }}
                <li class="list-group-item" v-model="newTodoText" v-for="task in list.data">
                    @{{ task}}
                </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</template>
```

In chrome dev tools, I can see both the log(city) and the log(tasks). So I'm gettings results from the API. But I can't figure out how to push it to the template. The error I'm receiving is `TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.todos.push')`

Comment: Where is `todos` defined? And `newTodoText`?

Answer (score 0):

Inside your `$.getJSON` success callback `this` is no longer your Vue instance.  You need to save a reference to your view before calling `$.getJSON`:

```
var vm = this;
$.getJSON(..., function(tasks) {
    ...
    vm.todos.push(...)
```

Or, look into [vue-resource](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-resource).  It supports the [Promise API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) and automatically binds the Vue instance inside callbacks so you can continue to reference `this`.  And it's a lot lighter than jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

in `data` you need to define a default value for `todos` and `newTodoText` like this

```
data: function () {
    return {
        list: [],
        todos: [],
        newTodoText: ''
    }
},
```